# Realm Java prepackaged database

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to put a preloaded Realm database in my app.

What I am doing:

1. I created a simple app that loads data from JSON to the Realm database (default1.realm).
2. I have my actual app, where I am trying to put the default.realm file created by the loader in the res/raw folder and using the Migration Examples copyBundledRealmFile() function to copy default.realm to getFilesDir().
3. After doing all this, when I try to do Realm.getInstance() then an empty Realm is returned.

What am I doing wrong?

```
String path3 = copyBundledRealmFile(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.default1), "default.realm");

Realm r1 = Realm.getInstance(this);
```

r1 should point to the file I copied, right?

UPDATE: I found why I could not access the database:

```
03-27 10:27:50.965  17750-17750/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: 
input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0x2e
03-27 10:27:50.965  17750-17750/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: 'Unspecified exception. 
Failure when converting long string to UTF-16 error_code = 2; retcode = 0; StringData.size = 40487; StringData.data = etc..

03-27 10:27:50.965  17750-17750/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: 
input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0x2e
03-27 10:27:50.965  17750-17750/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: 'Unspecified exception. 
Failure when converting long string to UTF-16 error_code = 2; retcode = 0; StringData.size = 40487; StringData.data =
```

My question would be now why is this error happening?

Comment: Which version of Realm are you using?

Comment: 0.80.0. This problem only happens when I am debugging and want to see results in the debugger. Could be also something from Android Studio.

Comment: I can see that you're using ART. Do you get the same error when using Dalvik?

Answer (score 0):

You say that your file is named `default.realm` and yet you refer to it as `default1` in the snippet above. Does it work if you try with `default`?

Comment: I just corrected my post, sorry for that. I made some progress, I removed the characters that cause the above mentioned error, but another came up: I am debugging Realm source code and when doing initializeRealm(realm) (line 529 in Realm.java) I can see the data what is in the file, meanwhile Realm is checking the tables and the fieldnames. But after that the returned Realm object has no tables, nothing.

Comment: It looks like your Realm file is corrupt. Is the file compressed while packaging, and you are opening a compressed Realm file? A compressed Realm file will look like a corrupt file.

Comment: There is no compression.

Comment: How can I check if the file is corrupt after packaging? Is there a way?

Comment: Opening a Realm file is probably the best thing to do. As the log show above indicates that you have a string of length 40487, my best guess is that something went wrong when packaging your app.

Comment: If you are using ProGuard, it might compress the Realm file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440572/proguard-breaking-audio-file-in-assets-or-raw

Comment: I am not using ProGuard either (at the moment) so that shouldn't be a problem either. I opened the realm file in a Realm Browser and I could see the content, so there should be also everything fine. Let me prepare a sample code and put it on github, so we can talk about actual code and not just theory.

Comment: I created the sample project here: https://github.com/gergokajtar/RealmLoader If you can take a look at it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I have cloned your sample project. First I ran the database loader app and copied the `default.realm` over and opened with the Realm browser - no problem. Then I built then app and it ran fine too. Opening the Realm files with the Realm browser worked fine. So I haven't been able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: By the way, I was using the emulator and not a real device. Can you tell me how you ran your apps when they failed?

Comment: Hi! I think I was confused when debugging. In the debugger when I was checking out the Realm object I could see 0 tables, so I thought that it cannot read the file. Sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks for the follow up!